# How to use a function within a function in python

Tags: python, function, loops, math

I want to use the function `f` in the function `radiationExposure`, but this code return nothing.

```
def f(x):
    import math
    return 10*math.e**(math.log(0.5)/5.27*x)


def radiationExposure(start, stop, step):    
    if start < 0 or stop < start or step < 0:
        print("Invalid inputs!")
    else:
        result = 0 # Total radiation exposure area
        for i in range(start, stop + 1):
            result += f(i)*step
        return result


radiationExposure(5, 10, 1)
```

Comment: Do you mean it returns nothing, or prints nothing?

Comment: it just returns nothing. it did not print out anything

Comment: Don't use local imports, they make it harder to understand your code and are usually only used to break cyclic dependencies (a bad thing to have), or to make conditional imports based e.g. on operating-system or availability of extension modules. No need for you to use them.

Comment: FWIW, it's better to do `math.exp(num)` than `math.e**num`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you run a Python script, it will *not* auto-echo the result. Your code runs fine, but you need to explicitly print the result:

```
print(radiationExposure(5, 10, 1))
```

Your script, when run, will now print `22.9424104106`.

Comment: but I thought my radiationExposure function will return a result?

Comment: It *does* return a result. But you are not doing anything with it. You need to print it, as Martijn showed you.